# Zeichensetzung bei Klammern

Tags: punctuation

Guten Tag

Es geht um folgenden Text (Information auf Kassenbon):

> Vielen Dank für Ihren Einkauf! Umtausch von ungetragener Ware mit Kassenbon und Etikette innerhalb von 30 Tagen möglich. (Ausgenommen Wäsche)

Die oben aufgeführte Version setzte Diskussionen in Gange betreffend Positionierung des Satzzeichens.

Als Parenthese und somit eingebettet zwischen *"Ware"* und *"mit"* sollte der Teil *"(Ausgenommen Wäsche)"* nicht gesetzt werden. Positioniert wurde er bewusst am Ende des Textes.

Folgende Varianten wurden Diskutiert: *"...Tagen möglich (ausgenommen Wäsche)."* und *"...Tagen möglich. (Ausgenommen Wäsche)"* und *"...Tagen möglich. (ausgenommen Wäsche)"*

Gibt es eine grammatikalisch "richtigere" Version?

Vielen Dank für die Unterstützung!

Comment: Da es sich nicht um einen vollständigen Satz handelt (kein Verb), wäre es auch richtig, den Punkt wegzulassen. Ansonsten gehören die Klammern zum Satz selbst und sollten sich vor dem Punkt befinden.

Answer (score 5):

[Duden-Regel 99, 3:](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/klammern)

> Der Schlusspunkt steht nur dann vor der schließenden Klammer, wenn ein
>   ganzer Satz eingeklammert ist, der nicht an den vorhergehenden Satz
>   angeschlossen sein soll.

Da in diesem Fall kein ganzer Satz eingeklammert wird, ist Folgendes jedenfalls richtig:

> Umtausch von ungetragener Ware mit Kassenbon und Etikette innerhalb
>   von 30 Tagen möglich (ausgenommen Wäsche).

Die beiden folgenden Versionen machen auf mich einen unrichtigen Eindruck, einen Beleg dafür habe ich allerdings nicht gefunden.

> - ... möglich. (Ausgenommen Wäsche)
> - ... möglich. (ausgenommen Wäsche)

Answer (score 1):

Vielen Dank für Ihren Einkauf! Umtausch von ungetragener Ware mit Kassenbon und Etikett innerhalb von 30 Tagen möglich (ausgenommen Wäsche).

oder

Vielen Dank für Ihren Einkauf! Der Umtausch von ungetragener Ware ist mit Kassenbon und Etikett innerhalb von 30 Tagen möglich (ausgenommen Wäsche).

Comment: Und warum sollen diese beiden Versionen richtiger sein, als die auf dem Kassenbon?

Comment: Zunächst einmal ist das einfach gute Praxis im professionellen Schriftsatz. Zweitens kannst du dann, wenn du willst, anfangen, logische Gründe zu suchen. Ein solcher wäre, dass das "ausgenommen Wäsche" inhaltlich so eng mit dem vorhergehenden Satz verbunden ist, dass es widersinnig wäre, es von diesem Satz durch Interpunktion zu trennen.

Comment: Bitte nicht nur ein paar Varianten auflisten, sondern auch dazuschreiben, welche davon man als besser oder schlechter als die ursprüngliche Version empfindet, und zwar bitte mit nachvollziehbarer Begründung!

Answer (score -1):

Wie Pollitzer in [seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38074/1487) richtig zitiert hat, wird ein Schlusspunkt nur dann vor der schließenden Klammer gesetzt, wenn in der Klammer ein ganzer Satz steht. Leider steht aber weder im Duden, noch sonst wo, was ein Satz ist.

In dem Wikipedia-Artikel [Satz (Grammatik)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_(Grammatik)#Begriff) steht:

> Es existieren vielfältige Ansätze, den Satzbegriff zu bestimmen, Sammlungen kommen auf annähernd 200 Definitionen von Satz. Jede linguistische Schule entwickelt ihren eigenen Satzbegriff. ...

Ich persönlich bin der Meinung, dass *»Ausgenommen Wäsche«* sehr wohl ein ganzer Satz ist (also kein Teil eines größeren Satzes). Es handelt sich hier um eine [Ellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)). Eine Ellipse ist ein Satz, bei dem etwas ausgelassen wurde (meist wird das Prädikat weggelassen). (Auch der weggelassene Teil wird als Ellipse bezeichnet, in diesem Sinn verwende ich den Begriff hier aber nicht.)

Fügt man zu *»Ausgenommen Wäsche«* ein auf der Hand liegendes Prädikat hinzu, entsteht aus dem unvollständigen (aber nichts desto trotz ganzen) Satz ein vollständiger:

> Ausgenommen **ist** Wäsche.

Unter diesem Gesichtspunkt kann gesagt werden:

- Die Großschreibung von *»Ausgenommen«* ist korrekt, weil es sich um das erste Wort eines Ganzsatzes handelt.
- Da ein ganzer Satz innerhalb der Klammer steht, müsste er eigentlich innerhalb der Klammer durch einen Schlusspunkt abgeschlossen werden.

Comment: "Ausgenommen Wäsche" ist meiner Ansicht nach kein Satz. Irgendjemand muss sagen "was außer" denn gemeint ist, bzw. von "was" Wäsche ausgenommen ist, alleine ergeben die zwei Worte keinen Sinn.

Comment: »Wäsche« ist das Subjekt des Satzes (Nominativ singular). Das Wort »ausgenommen« ist ein Prädikativum, es ist das Partizip Perfekt von »ausnehmen« und es ist ein Teil des Prädikats des Satzes. Was dem Satz zur Vollständigkeit noch fehlt (und ihn zu einer Ellipse macht), ist ein Prädikatsverb. Am naheliegendsten ist anzunehmen, dass das Verb »ist« fehlt. Der vollständige Satz lautet dann: »Wäsche ist ausgenommen.« Die Struktur des Satzes ist dieselbe wie in »Feuer ist ausgebrochen.« Umreihen ergibt: »Ausgebrochen ist Feuer.« »Ausgenommen ist Wäsche.« Da muss niemand mehr etwas dazusagen. ...

Comment: Das, wovon Wäsche ausgenommen ist, steht ja im Satz davor: *Umtausch.* Diskutieren kann man eigentlich nur noch darüber, ob »Wäsche ausgenommen« (bzw. »Ausgenommen Wäsche) ein *ganzer* Satz ist. Es ist sicher kein vollständiger Satz (sondern eine Ellipse), aber nachdem unmittelbar davor ein Satz durch einen Schlusspunkt abgeschlossen wurde, und danach nichts mehr kommt, ist das Wortgefüge sicherlich kein Teil eines Satzes der dieses Wortgefüge beinhaltet, sondern entweder selbst ein **ganzer** Satz oder etwas anderes als ein Satz. ...

Comment: Und dass es sich um einen Satz (nämlich eine Ellipse) handelt, habe ich hoffentlich bereits klar genug herausgearbeitet.